# How can I add commands to startup requiring admin privileges?

Tags: startup, privileges

I want add commands to my startup list that needs admin privileges, how do I go about it? Obviously there's no chance of me typing in the password when the computer is starting up.

**NOTE** At this time, I won't be able to verify if any of the answers would actually work, so I'd appreciate if someone can provide a solution that has actually worked in practice.

Comment: There are several old questions about the same argument. Have you given a look?

Comment: @enzotib, didn't find em in a quick search.

Comment: This is one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45631/any-file-executed-once-when-system-starts-up

Comment: @enzotib, that doesn't say anything about commands with admin privileges for commands executed with log in.

Comment: If it's command at GDM, it's beyond users and naturally under root.

Comment: Have you read all the answers? See also this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up-of-ubuntu. Moreover, it can be useful to know if as startup you mean boot time, display manager start time, graphical login time, general login time, or what else.

Comment: @enzotib, night here, getting a bit confused, will get back at you later. Just to make things clear, I just want to run a command that needs admin privileges when I log in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**

Simply add your commands at the end of the file /etc/rc.local (but **before** the `exit 0` line!)

**Long answer**

Of course there's also the *Debian way* of doing this - writing a script. Put it in the `/etc/init.d/` directory.

Lets say you called it FOO. You then run `% update-rc.d FOO defaults`. You also have to make the file you created, FOO, executable, using `$chmod +x FOO`.

You can check out `% man update-rc.d` for more information. It is a Debian utility to install scripts. The option `defaults` puts a link to start FOO in run levels 2, 3, 4 and 5 (and puts a link to stop FOO into 0, 1 and 6.)

To make the script run as last:

```
update-rc.d -f my_script_name defaults 99
```

Comment: No issues with admin privileges? And won't it effect all the users on the system?