# Run commands on system startup

Tags: command-line, startup, autorun

I need some help with running commands on system startup.

So, I need these two commands to be executed every time I start my machine, due a problem with my Realtek driver (doesn't really matter):

```
sudo ifconfig myCode up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

How do I manage that to work?

I'm getting confused with sudo command and not knowing when will I enter my password or will the script even be run. Sorry for my low knowledge of Ubuntu system.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Since your commands are `sudo`, you should have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/46953/how-can-i-add-commands-to-startup-requiring-admin-privileges?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Add `ifconfig myCode` up & `service network-manager restart` at the end of the `/etc/rc.local` before "exit 0"

Comment: I did, but it doesnt seem to do the right job. It only took fer minutes to change between login screen and actual desktop

Comment: sound like an issue with your commands, you might want to open a new question for that.